# Break promise chain into seperate functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

break into two functions:

```
public valJson(json, schemaFile: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(schemaFile)
            .toPromise()
            .then(fileContents => fileContents.json())
            .then((schema) => {
                let ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
                ajv.validate(schema, json) ? 
                resolve() :
                reject(new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText()));
            }, err => reject(
                new Error("Unable to get schema file contents:" + err))
            );
    });
};
```

There is really 3 things this function does so it isn't very good to unit test.

1. get file contents
2. parse them to json
3. validate the json

How can this be broken up to make each of those tasks unit testable?

Attempt 1 at breaking the actual validation part out is not going well:

```
public valJson(json, schemaFile: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(schemaFile)
            .toPromise()
            .then(fileContents => fileContents.json())
            .then((schema) => {
                this.valJ(schema)
            }, err => reject(
                new Error("Unable to get schema file contents:" + err))
            );
    });
};

    valJ(schema, json) {
        let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
        if ajv.validate(schema, json) 
            return resolve()
        reject(new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText()));
    }
}
```

update - As per the feedback I'm trying to stop using anonymous functions and then I will try to not create a new promise. I'm here:

```
public valJson(json, schemaFile: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var getFilePromise = this.http.get(schemaFile)
            .toPromise();
    var parseToJsonPromise = getFilePromise
            .then(contents => this.toJson(contents));
    var validateJsonPromise = parseToJsonPromise.then(schema => this.valJ(schema, json, resolve, reject),
            err => reject(
                new Error("Unable to get schema file contents:" + err))
            );
    });
};

toJson(fileContents): any {
    return fileContents.json()
}

valJ(schema, json, resolve, reject): any {
    let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
    ajv.validate(schema, json) ?
        resolve() :
        reject(new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText())
    );
}
```

Comment: You're doing the promise anti-pattern (google it). `.http.get().toPromise()` returns a promise so **don't** create `new Promise()` yourself. Instead just return the promise returned by `.http.get().toPromise()`;

Comment: Your anonymous functions do not have to be anonymous.  You can break them out as separately defined functions with well known inputs and expected outputs.  Then, you just put the name of the separately declared function in the implementation.  Then, you can test each of them separately.  The only time this becomes difficult is if you are using variables from parent scope.  Then, the only way to break out the code into separately declared functions at a higher scope where you can call them independently is to pass those variables into them rather than use them directly from the parent scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
public valJson(json, schemaFile: string) {
  return this.fetchSchema(schemaFile)
    .then(res => this.parseSchema(res))
    .then(schema => this.validateWithSchema(json, schema));
}

fetchSchema(url) {
  return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}

parseSchema(response) {
  return response.json();
}

validateWithSchema(json, schema) {
  let ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
  if (!ajv.validate(schema, json)) {
    throw new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText())
  }
}
```